# CS50/Substitution – Why does the tolower() function not work in my code?

Tags: c, cs50

Can someone explain if I switch

```
// 3.3 Must not contained repeated letters |
if (toupper(argv[1][j] == toupper(argv[1][k])))
```

to

```
if (tolower(argv[1][j] == tolower(argv[1][k])))
```

why it doesn't work anymore, even though the letters could be the same the computer doesn't recognize it?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc,string argv[])  
{
    int count_key_char = 0;
    int count_repeated_char = 0;

    //Exactly 1 command line argument
    if (argc == 2)
    {
        //Must all be letters
        for (int i = 0; i < strlen(argv[1]); i++)
        {
            if (isalpha(argv[1][i]))
            {
                count_key_char++;
            }
        }
        // 3.3 Must not contained repeated character/s
        for (int j = 0, n = strlen(argv[1]); j < n; j++)
        {
            for (int k = j + 1; k < n; k++)
            {
                if (toupper(argv[1][j] == toupper(argv[1][k])))
                {
                    count_repeated_char++;
                }
            }
        }
        // Must be 26 characters (Fail criteria)
        if (strlen(argv[1]) != 26)
        {
            printf("Key must contain 26 characters.\n");
            return 1;
        }
        // Must be all letters  (Fail criteria)
        else if (count_key_char != strlen(argv[1]))
        {
            printf("Key must only contain alphabetic characters.\n");
            return 1;
        }
        // Must not contained repeated character/s (Fail criteria)
        else if (count_repeated_char != 0)
        {
            printf("Key must not contain repeated characters.\n");
            return 1;
        }
        // 4. Get plaintext; Prompt user for plaintext
        else
        {
            string plaintext = get_string("Plaintext: ");
            printf("ciphertext: ");

            for (int w = 0; w < strlen(plaintext); w++)
            {
                // If character are letter & uppercase
                if (isalpha(plaintext[w]) && isupper(plaintext[w]))
                {
                    int upper = (plaintext[w] -65);
                    printf("%c", toupper(argv[1][upper]));
                }
                // If character are lower & lowercase
                else if (isalpha(plaintext[w]) && islower(plaintext[w]))
                {
                    int lower = (plaintext[w] - 97);
                    printf("%c", tolower(argv[1][lower]));
                }
                // If character are not letter, print as it is
                else
                {
                    printf("%c", plaintext[w]);
                }
            }
            printf("\n");
            return 0;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Usage: ./substitution key\n");
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you calling `toupper` *inside* of the arguments to another call to `toupper`?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a misplaced close paren `)` in this line

```
if (toupper(argv[1][j] == toupper(argv[1][k])))
```

The `toupper` will fail if the letters are lower case; the `tolower` will fail if the letters are upper case.
It is evaluating this

`argv[1][j] == toupper(argv[1][k])`

which will return 1 (true) if both characters are the same upper case letter. If the key is entered in lower case line will return 0 (false) and  program will not consider it a repeated character.

Properly enclose the `toupper` argument in parentheses and the problem will be solved.

Comment: yeah you were right, now it all makes sense. Thanks mate